# Is it possible to read WhatsApp messages programmatically?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to read WhatsApp message in my application, is it possible? Is there any API available to read WhatsApp messages? Is it possible to send messages from another application and message is received in WhatsApp application account?

Comment: did you find way to read messages?

Comment: @PouriaHemati Did you find anything related to.. ?

Answer (score 3):

Whatsapp store all messages in an encrypted database (pyCrypt) which is very easy to decipher using Python.

You can fetch this database easily on Android, iPhone, Blackberry and dump it into html file. Here(http://geeknizer.com/read-extract-whatsapp-messages-android-iphone-blackberry/) are complete instructions: Read, Extract WhatsApp Messages backup on Android, iPhone, Blackberry

Disclaimer: I researched and wrote this extensive guide.

Comment: 2 questions: Is this qpproach still up to date? Since the article is from 2013 and the answer from 2017. And Second: Can I legally decrypt the messages of the user with his approval? Doesnt that violate some whatsapp guideline?

Comment: @telion Encryption is done for a Reason to  stop unauthorized access. Your 2nd Questions Answer.

Comment: Does anyone know why the site in the link was blocked by my malware detection???

Comment: did you find any solution ??

Comment: how to get real time DataBase whatssapp ?